# React Fetch API quote random generator

Tags: reactjs

```
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quoteData: [],
      quote: '',
      author: ''
    }
    this.randomQuote = this.randomQuote.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const API = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/'
    fetch(API)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({
              quoteData: data.quotes
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Error', error));

    this.randomQuote();
  }

  randomQuote() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quoteData.length);
    return this.quoteData[randomNumber];
  }

  handleClick() {
    const oneRandomQuote = this.randomQuote();
    this.setState({
      quote: oneRandomQuote.quote,
      author: oneRandomQuote.author
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='quote-box'>
        <h1 id='text'>
          {this.state.quote}
        </h1>
        <h3 id='author'>
          - {this.state.author}
        </h3>
        <Buttons handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className='buttons'>
        <a id='tweet-quote' className='button' href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=${this.props.quote} - ${this.props.author}`}><i className='fab fa-twitter'></i></a>
        <button id='new-quote' className='button' onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
          New quote
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <QuoteBox />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I am building a random quote generator with React by fetching API
I tried but, since I am a beginner of programming, I need some guideline from the code above I am stuck in.

I tried to set a bunch of quote data fetched to quoteData and render quote and author in the quote data but it does not work in a way I expected.

Comment: what do you get as response??

Comment: There is a typo. 

Use this.state.quoteData instead of this.quoteData.

Comment: @ Anitta Paul it does not show up any quote. I am building this in Codepen. Console spit out Object error

Comment: @fjplaurr alright thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change `this.quoteData` to `this.state.quoteData`, because the quote is in the state variable. In order to show a quote before the button click, call the `handleClick()` in the `setState` call back. Check the changed code

```
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quoteData: [],
      quote: '',
      author: ''
    }
    this.randomQuote = this.randomQuote.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const API = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/'
    fetch(API)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({
              quoteData: data.quotes
            },()=>{
              // add handle click function here, so that a random quote in shown on initial load
              this.handleClick();
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Error', error));
        // remove randomQuote() call from here, there is no use of that call here.

  }

  randomQuote() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quoteData.length);
    return this.state.quoteData[randomNumber];
  }

  handleClick() {
    const oneRandomQuote = this.randomQuote();
    this.setState({
      quote: oneRandomQuote.quote,
      author: oneRandomQuote.author
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='quote-box'>
        <h1 id='text'>
          {this.state.quote}
        </h1>
        <h3 id='author'>
          - {this.state.author}
        </h3>
        <Buttons handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className='buttons'>
        <a id='tweet-quote' className='button' href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=${this.props.quote} - ${this.props.author}`}><i className='fab fa-twitter'></i></a>
        <button id='new-quote' className='button' onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
          New quote
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change your randomQUote function like below. You are trying to return something from your **this** scope which does not exist.

```
randomQuote() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quoteData.length);
    return this.state.quoteData[randomNumber];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I found it. I got a quote when I clicked the button. Can you give me a little bit of advice so that I could see the quote even before I clicked the button?

Comment: Glad i could help then can yuou accept the answer ?